# React children rendering procedure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree, render

I have a doubt regarding children stuff in react. I know there are documents that tell about this thing but an exact explanation could be better.

Let's say that my react component tree is like this.(for simplicity  have added only 2 levels could be more)

```
         A
    A1       A2
 A11 A12   A21 A22
```

A has 2 children A1 and A2 and both have 2 children as shown. (children as tree structure not react children thing).

Now the component A22 is dependent on A only it takes props from A and should re render based on the props given by A.

Now to solve that I did that I rendered A22 in A like this

```
render(){
    return (
      <otherThing/>
      <A2>
         <A22 {propsForA22}/>
      </A2>
    );
}
```

cool now A2 is the parent of A22 react tree wise but the rendering is done by A.

1. Now can anyone explain order in which the way lifecycle methods will happen for A, A2, A22.
2. What will happen if A2 re-renders will it cause A22 to re-render.
3. if A re-renders but no props for A2 changes lets say that its shouldComponent update blocks updation in that case what will happen about A22.

Comment: Please post relevant answers only. will post answer myself after doing some research.

Answer (score 0):

I waited for a day and rather then trying to find a solution just by thinking one of my friend told me to try it out and find for myself.

So I checked through things.

> 1. Order of lifecycle methods.

the simplest thing to find first is to find the order in which the components instantiate and render. later we can find how things go in case of re-rendering on state change.

(this is the link of the jsfiddle).

so my component tree is like this only.

```
         A
   A1       A2
A11       A21 A22
```

and A22 is rendered in A but passed as child to A2 which finally puts it into the react tree.

[image]

So I got result as above. Bit strange I thought A was instantiating A22 but it is instantiated after A2 and A21.
So basically we can say maybe A22 is instantiated by A but it is done in DFS form so after instantiating A2 only A22 is getting created.

Ok now lets add all the lifecycle methods and find out some more.

[image]

oh this is new information that A1 was instantiated, mounting started and rendered before A2 but the A1 didMount happened after A1 and all its children were rendered (ok will find more about it).

Ok Now lets check about the re-rendering of A22 and A.

[image]
the third thing happening is the lifecycle methods on state change of A everything re-renders and the order has nothing to do with A22 being written in A in place of A2.

Now lets see things with Pure component.

[image]

After adding pureComponent (shouldComponentUpdate = this.props!==nextProps)

A1 tree does not re-renders. A2 re-renders A22 re-renders. As A22 was consuming the changed state. and A2 re-renders because the children prop changed(i guess) and here also A2 receiveProps and render happen exactly as the react tree still no effect of writing A22 in A.

> One doubt left if A22 is re-rendered after A2 then what changed in A2
>   props.children. A22 is changed after rendering of A2.

final link of jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/mersL9hk/3/)